# Interpreting wireshark output

Tags: sniffing, wireshark

The ascii window of a wireshark capture has a lot of dots (.). What do they mean exactly? What info do these dots imply?

Comment: Those are non-ascii binary data. Btw , this question is irrelevant to security.

Comment: This means wireshark uses ascii to decode bit strings? Why not use something like unicode which would understand all text irrespective of the language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What info do these dots imply?

They represent non-printable characters - things like newlines, carriage feeds, EOF, NUL, etc. etc.  You can look at the corresponding hex code (to the left) to figure out what the actual byte is.

Consider this example displaying the 'Certificate' packet from an HTTPS server to the client.  The 'Certificate' TLS message contains both binary and textual data; the text comes from the certificate itself:

[image: Wireshark TLS snippet]

Note that I've selected the 'Certificate Length' field, which shows that the length of the certificate is 1336 bytes.  But if you look at the highlighted bytes, with the "text" on the right, it doesn't say "1336", it says "..8".  That's because "..8" is the ASCII representation of 0x000538.

If you look at an [ASCII table](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ascii.7.html), you'll see that 0x00 is "NUL (null character)", 0x05 is "ENQ (enquiry)", and 0x38 is "8".  NUL and ENQ are non-printable - they cannot be displayed - so Wireshark prints a "." instead.

But in the underlying protocol, those aren't text in any case.  It's a 24-bit integer - hexadecimal 000538 is equal to decimal 1336, indicating the following certificate is 1336 bytes long.

And going further down, once the certificate starts, we see normal ASCII text data ("Entrust, Inc.") mingled with binary non-text data ("..U...0").

Even with a fully "text based" protocol like HTTP, you'll see '.' for non-printable characters.  Note the ".." after "Connection: close" which corresponse to "Carriage Return - Line Feed" (CRLF, or \r\n):

[image: Wireshark HTTP snippet]

> This means wireshark uses ascii to decode bit strings? Why not use something like unicode which would understand all text irrespective of the language?

In short, Wireshark is merely displaying bytes, which may or may not be text, but if they are text they're likely to be ASCII and not Unicode.

Wireshark displays data bytes - both string and binary - as ASCII characters, with the '.' being used to denote any non-printable character.  There are many, many network protocols which use ASCII characters to communicate on the wire - FTP, SMTP, Telnet, HTTP, IRC, etc. etc.  If a network protocol uses text to communicate, then it is almost certainly using ASCII.

I am not familiar with any protocols which use UTF/Unicode as the basis for communication.  Any protocol - such as HTTP - which wishes to communicate Unicode **data** will signal *at the application layer* that the following bytes are to be interpreted as Unicode.  (I do not know for sure, but I would expect that Wireshark interpreters which can catch that and display appropriately exist, but they would still display ASCII in the "Packet Bytes" windows, because that's what those are - bytes - 8 bit units - best displayed in an 8-bit text format like ASCII.)